# Groupby and rolling mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an example of a DataFrame as shown below:

```
 Group    Col_A     Col_B     Col_C
   A        1         1         10
   B        5         7          9
   C        3         5          3
   A        2         2          2
   B        1         5          9
   C        7         7          7
   A       50        100        100
```

I would like to group by the column 'Group' calculate the last 2 occurrences and find the mean, then replace the other columns with their respective value.

I know that if I only do:

```
 df.groupby('Group').mean()
```

I'll get a dataframe with 'Group' as index and other columns as columns and their value is the mean and not the last 2 occurrences' mean. Plus, the replacing is kind of twisted.

I would like to get :

```
 Group    Col_A     Col_B     Col_C
   A        1         1         10
   B        5         7          9
   C        3         5          3
   A       1.5       1.5         6
   B        3         6          9
   C        5         6         10
   A       26        51         51
```

It clearly needs an advanced level of manipulating groupby and tweaking performance.
Thank you for your help !

Here's an example of the data that can be loaded:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = '''\
Group,Col_A,Col_B,Col_C
A,1,1,10
B,5,7,9
C,3,5,3
A,2,2,2
B,1,5,9
C,7,7,7
A,50,100,100
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rolling after a groupby. So here, I would use:

```
df.groupby('Group').rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(level=0).sort_index()
```

It gives as expected:

```
  Group  Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
0     A    1.0    1.0   10.0
1     B    5.0    7.0    9.0
2     C    3.0    5.0    3.0
3     A    1.5    1.5    6.0
4     B    3.0    6.0    9.0
5     C    5.0    6.0    5.0
6     A   26.0   51.0   51.0
```